# How to declare async generator function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, generator

I am trying to create async generator function in Node.js, but it seems to be impossible.

**Version of my Node.js**: 7.6.0.

**My code**:

```
async function* async_generator(){
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    yield await call_to_async_func(i);
  };
}
```

**Error I got**:

[image]

Does anyone knows what is the problem? Why I can't create async generator function while I can create generator function or async function Independently?

Comment: Async generators don’t exist as of ES2018 as far as I know?

Comment: There was a proposal ([here](https://github.com/jhusain/asyncgenerator)) but it's been withdrawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There simply are no asynchronous generator functions in Node.js.

Yet. They're still figuring out what their semantics would be, see the [*async iteration* proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-async-iteration).

Comment: This answer is not relevant anymore since asynchronous generators became standard in ES6.

Comment: @gyo This answer is - as of now - still up to date, asynchronous generators are still in the stage-3 draft linked above. Promises became standard with ES6, `async`/`await` became standard with ES8.

Comment: that's correct, it's definitely not "standard" yet but generators are supported by all the recent browsers (except IE, Edge has limited support) and the latest version of Node (currently v10)

Answer (score 8):

It is there and it does work, but currently it is behind a harmony flag.

example.js

```
async function* async_generator() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    yield await new Promise(r => setTimeout(_ => r("hello world"), 100))
  };
}

async function main(){
  for await (let item of async_generator()){
    console.log(item);
  }
}

main().catch(console.log);
```

run with (works for me in node v8.5.0)

```
node --harmony-async-iteration example.js
```

be aware that the proposal is still at stage-3 and if you want to use it in the browser you'll likely also need to transpile with typescript or babel.

update:

as of node 9, async generators are staged. You can enable it simply with `--harmony`.

Comment: with node 10 they are now enabled by default